# CLion code formatting: add a newline before catch

Tags: c++, clion

If I write a code like following,

```
try
{
    //Some code
}
catch
{
    //Some code
}
```

And then pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to reformat code, code gets converted to following.

```
try
{
    //Some code
} catch
{
    //Some code
}
```

(I have modified the code formatting styles so that braces are not wrapped to the previous line)

I need to keep the catch in a new line, without taking it to the same line as the previous `}`. Is there any way I can tell CLion to keep the catch clause in the new line without wrapping it to the previous line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change this in the settings:

`File` -> `Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `C/C++` ->`Wrapping and Braces` -> `'try' statement` -> Tick `'catch' on new line`